# model.predict() returns classes and not probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

**Hello!**

I am using Keras for first time. 
I trained and saved a model. *(as a json file and its weights too)*
The model it is intended to classify an image among 3 classes.
My compile method :

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After that, I load the model and its weights and i try to make a prediction for a random image

```
# Predicting images
img =image.load_img('/path/to/image/index.jpeg', target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
#normilize the array output
x *= (255.0/x.max())
image = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
image = preprocess(image)
preds = loaded_model.predict(image,)
pred_classes = np.argmax(preds)
print(preds)
print(pred_classes)
```

How to i get a list with the probabilities? 
For example `[75% 15% 10%]`
Currently i get as an output

```
[[5.571262e-21 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00]]
2
```

This is the model summary `print(loaded_model.summary())`
Model successfully loaded from disk!

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #  
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 222, 222, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 222, 222, 64)      0        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 111, 111, 64)      0        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 109, 109, 64)      36928    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 109, 109, 64)      0        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 54, 54, 64)        0        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 52, 52, 128)       73856    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 52, 52, 128)       0        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 26, 26, 128)       0        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 24, 24, 256)       0        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 256)       0        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 512)       1180160  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 10, 10, 512)       0        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 512)         0        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 12800)             0        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               6554112  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 512)               0        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 1539      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)    (None, 3)                 0        
=================================================================
Total params: 8,143,555
Trainable params: 8,143,555
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Did you try `.predict_proba()` instead of `predict()` ?

Comment: Yeap I get the exact same output!

Comment: Your output does look like probabilities to me. The values look like you are using softmax at the last layer. These leads to tiny numbers. Just multiply these numbers by 100 and round them off, you will get your percentages

Comment: I know that it seems like probs but actually they are [0 0 1]
I works like predict_classes.I am looking for better probabilities.
Like as i said [0.7 0.15 0.1]. Also as the last layer i use sigmoid

Comment: The output you shown are probabilities. The values 0, 0, 1 just means that your model is 100% confident that this sample belongs to class2. For better probabilities you need to make sure that your model is not over-fitting and enough data is present to train it.

Comment: Thank you for your time! But whatever image i try i get a different combination of this [1 0 0]. I mean shouldn't it at least, in some images output something more random like [0.5 0.3 0.2] even if it is overfitted??

Comment: This line of code seems to be invalid: `x *= (255.0/x.max())`. Try `x /= (255.0/x.max())` or `x /= 255`.

Answer (score -1):

You already have the probabilities :)

Look at your list:

```
[[5.571262e-21 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00]]
```

and the probabilities are:

```
0, 0, 1
```

Btw, it looks like the **overfitting**. Check this page:
https://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/04/preventing-overfitting-neural-networks.html

Comment: Thank you for your time! 
But whatever image i try i get a different combination of this [1 0 0].
I mean shouldn't it at least, in some images output something more random like [0.5 0.3 0.2] even if it is overfitted??

Comment: You are right, that is why I wrote: "it looks like over-fitting.". I suggest you apply some regularization to your network. If you need more help, please add your model summary using `model.summary()`

Comment: i uploaded! Check it out!

Comment: try to reduce number of filters in your CNN + maybe another optimizer would work better try nadam or SGD. Btw, how big is your dataset?

Comment: Is not that big.I train on 2000 pictures and i validate on 800.
But i use data augmentation