# Keras - model.predict return classes and not probabilities

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I load a model I trained.
This is the last layer from training:

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After that I try to make a prediction to a random image.
So I load the model:

```
#load the model we created
json_file = open('/path/to/model_3.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weight into model
loaded_model.load_weights("/path/to/model_3.h5")
print("\nModel successfully loaded from disk! ")


# Predicting images
img =image.load_img('/path/to/image.jpeg', target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x *= (255.0/x.max())
image = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
image = preprocess(image)
preds = loaded_model.predict_proba(image)
pred_classes = np.argmax(preds)
print(preds)
print(pred_classes)
```

As an output I get this:

```
[[6.0599333e-26 0.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00]]
2
```

Which basically it is like I get `[0 0 1]`
like `predict_classes`. Though I would like to get probabilities.
So I am searching for an output like `[0.75 0.1 0.15]`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the same question with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621833/model-predict-returns-classes-and-not-probabilities ? Are you possibly the same user??

Answer (score 5):

If you want's probabilities as output of the network you just need to use softmax activation function instead of sigmoid

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I changed to softmax now i get [1 0 0

Comment: which is a distribution, that just means that the network is sure its the first one. There are other functions like "log-softmax" which give less confident probabilities as output but i think softmax si the only one provided by keras

Comment: Ok i see! But is it normal for every foto i tried to get combinations of this ? ([0 1 0]). I mean the network is so sure about all the photos?

Comment: For example i trained the model to pictures of birds and cats and the third class is a class which has mixed photos. That is the probability that an image wont be not a bird nor a cat.When i try to classify an image with a cat and a person, i should get fro example [ 0,45 0,45 0,1] for classes [cat, random, bird]. But i get just [1, 0 ,0].Thats why i am telling i dont get probabilities!

Comment: softmax tend to generate vector where only one is high and all the rest are low, but if you get always two zeros and a one it's a bit strange. in the case of a cat + human being 1 0 0 it makes sense because if your network is learning to classify between cat and bird if it sees a cat it's likely to say it's a cat for sure, the network has no idea that there is a human in the picture. But make sure you are not overfitting, that may be another reason why the output is always one hot

Comment: so if i have 1700 training pictures 
and 700 validation pictures .
How should i train? I use 1700 for training and 6500 for vaidation with batch = 16

Comment: how do you use 6500 validation pictures if you said you have only 700?

Comment: i meant 650 validation pictures